# How to add an image over an existing image?

Tags: dm-script

With two images, I can do a copy and paste of one image onto the other.
How can I do this in scripting?  I tried the following script:

```
image front := c    //  e.g., raster image; may need to adjust letter
imageDisplay front_dspl = front.imageGetImageDisplay(0)
imageDocument front_doc = ImageGetOrCreateImageDocument(front)
number tt = front_doc.ImageDocumentCountImages()
OkDialog("# of images: " + tt)
    
image test := e     //  e.g., a profile; may need to adjust letter

ImageDocumentAddImageDisplay( front_doc, test, 4)
```

When I run the script the first time, the OKDialog returns 1
When I run the script the second time, the OKDialog returns 2

but no profile shows up in image test.  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your own answer does what you want (I've edited in a one-liner version.)

But you can also do it based on your original idea:

```c
image from := a    //  e.g., raster image; may need to adjust letter
image to := c     //  e.g., a profile; may need to adjust letter
imageDocument toDoc = to.ImageGetOrCreateImageDocument()
toDoc.ImageDocumentAddImageDisplay( from.ImageClone(), "best" )
// toDoc.ImageDocumentSwitchToPageMode()
```

However, in doing so, you add the image (or a clone of it) to the imageDocument at root-level, not as a child of the existing imageDisplay.
You will only see it, if you switch the destination imageDocument into "page mode".

Answer (score 1):

Just run into the answer myself:

```
image front := b    //  raster image;  may need to adjust letter
imageDisplay front_dspl = front.imageGetImageDisplay(0)
imageDocument front_doc = ImageGetOrCreateImageDocument(front)
Component front_comp = front_dspl
    
image test := d     //  e.g., a profile;  may need to adjust letter
imageDisplay test_dspl = test.imageGetImageDisplay(0)
Component test_comp = test.imageGetImageDisplay(0)
Component new_comp = ComponentClone( test_comp, 1 ) 
ComponentAddChildAtBeginning(front_comp, new_comp)
```

The componentClone() is important.

---

Shorthand version:

```
image from := A
image to := B
to.ImageGetImageDisplay(0).ComponentAddChildAtEnd( from.ImageGetImageDisplay(0).ComponentClone(1))
```